# Forward Variadic Argument List to ncurses printw function in c

Tags: c, variadic-macros

This has been asked in several different flavors. Yet I can still not get it to work. Here is my function definition.

```
void                                                                           
ncurses_add_line(const char *fmt, ...)                                         
{                                                                              
  if (ncurses_window) {                                                        
    va_list args;                                                              
    va_start(args, fmt);                                                       
    printw(fmt, args);                                                           
    printw("\n");                                         
    va_end(args);                                                              
  }                                                                            
}
```

When I call this function I get gibberish in the variadic print out of my function. If I call `printw` directly it all works. For example, if I call `ncurses_add_line` like `ncurses_add_line("Hello %d", var)` I get a value not store in var. However, if I call `printw("Hello %d", var)`, I see the value of var displayed next to "Hello" as in, if var == 1 then "Hello 1" is printed with `printw` but this is not the case for `ncurses_add_line`.

What do I need to change?

My reason for wrapping this up is because I don't want to include  in my header file, only in my c file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `vwprintw` instead of `printw`.  [vwprintw](https://linux.die.net/man/3/vwprintw) takes a va_list as its argument.

The idiom you're trying to use -- passing a va_list to a function that takes a variable number of arguments -- won't work.  One solution is to find a variant of the function that will work (in this case, vwprintw).  An alternative is to "flatten" the va_list: in this case, you could use vsprintf to create a formatted string, and then pass that into curses.

Answer (score 1):

`args` is *not* something like an array of arguments. It is an internal structure. You have to read out every single argument by passing the type. Please keep in mind, that in C there is no runtime reflection, so you have to add the types in your code.

```
void ncurses_add_line(const char *fmt, ...)                                         
{                                                                              
if (ncurses_window) 
{            
  va_list args; 
  va_start(args, fmt);       
  char *arg = va_arg( args, int ); // take out one arg by giving the type (int)
  printw(fmt, arg);   
  printw("\n");                                         
  va_end(args);                                                              
  }                                                                            
}
```